# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@d674dcb: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881394 at offset 508

Tags: android, kotlin, parcel

I just got that Error with Android 12 Device

For devices running on android lower than 12 everything is ok !

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@d674dcb: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881394 at offset 508
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3771)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2318)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8306)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
```

Here my code

```
   val intent= Intent(this,MyInfosActivity::class.java)
      var bundle = Bundle()
      bundle.putParcelable(STORE_DATA, storeData)
      intent.putExtras(bundle)
      startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_WISHLIST)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with that :

In my Parcelable file the problem is with String value null

I fix that with

```
  if (cityName != null)
  {
   dest.writeString(cityName);
  }
```

Hope this helps you